# Accessing Dataverse/Power App Data on external Public Website via API

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, webapi, dataverse

I am stumped trying to find a similar idea on how we can achieve this.

We are currently using a model-driven power app/Dataverse to house school applications. Once an application is submitted, our representatives will begin updating the application record "Application Status" custom field as they are going through the various steps.

Our partner wants to create a external website (just simple HTML/CSS/JavaScript) to display an application lookup where applicants can type in their application ID or send applicants direct-links to view the status of their application. (example: domain.com/application-status/?appid=1234)

This external, public website would have to connect to our dataverse/power app via the web api to make the request and display it to the applicant searching/viewing the website.

How can this be achieved? All I have read is that the user looking up data will need to have a Microsoft account and authenticated in our environment to view the data.

Can someone point me in the right direct on how to get this done (article or existing thread). Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally being handled by the use of a PowerPlatform Portal.
Portals are designed to allow interactions with B2B/B2C.
This is, however, a hefty price tag.

Another way is to make your website use Rest API calls to your Dataverse tables.
To enable these, you need to create a client application registration in Azure and add this application user in your environment as an application user. Once registered, assign the appropriate rights(Sysadmin, Syscustomizer, whatever you want) and you can access your environment in two steps:

1. Generate an access token based on the scope of your environment, client id, and client secret.
2. Use the access token your application user has given to do your CRUD operations.